# Need to take click into account on this jquery

Tags: jquery, html

This simple jquery shows some text info when user press certain keys. Its works fine, except that not not shows text "Loading..." if user click on that hyperlink.

How to solve this, am total noob in jquery.

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(
function () {
    $(document).keydown(
        function(e) {
          var url = false;
          if (e.which == 37) { url = $('.pret a').attr('href'); }
          else if (e.which == 39) { url = $('.sled a').attr('href'); }
           if (url) { $('div.A37-sheet').hide().html('<center><p>Loading...</p></center>').load(window.location = url).fadeIn(); }
        });
  });
```

HTML part:

```
<li class="pret button" style="left:0; top:50%; position:fixed">
<a class="kggkFX" style="outline: 0;" href="'.$pretlokacija.'"><img src="images/prev.png"></a>
</li>
<li class="sled button" style="right:0; top:50%; position:fixed">
<a class="kggkFX" style="outline: 0;" href="'.$sledlokacija.'"><img src="images/idigore.png"></a>
</li>
```

Comment: please modify your html part

Comment: If you're attaching an event listener to the document you don't need to wait for document ready.

Comment: @Musa I need that document ready.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't catch `click` event. That is why nothing works when user click hyperlink. Add this please:

```
$( '.kggkFX' ).click( function( event ){
  event.preventDefault();
  var a = $( event.target ),
      url = a.attr( 'href' ),
      container = $( 'div.A37-sheet' ),
      loader = '<center><p>Loading...</p></center>';
  container.hide().html( loader ).load( window.location = url ).fadeIn();
});
```

But code is better when you trying to don't repeat yourself. Now we have two pretty the same event handlers. Good practice would be to rewrite all your code to:

```
$(document).ready( function(){
  $( document ).keydown( function( event ) {
        if( e.which == 37 )
          $('.pret a').click();
        else if( e.which == 39 )
          $('.sled a').click();
  });

  $( '.kggkFX' ).click( function( event ){
      event.preventDefault();
      var a = $( event.target ),
          url = a.attr( 'href' ),
          container = $( 'div.A37-sheet' ),
          loader = '<center><p>Loading...</p></center>';
      container.hide().html( loader ).load( window.location = url ).fadeIn();
  });
});
```

Comment: Works like а charm... Спасибо

Answer (score 0):

I think here the need is delay.

May settimeout or something else will work here.

Comment: Thnx for tip. I was thinking about that indeed.